# Bash script executed within Python with os.systems returns 0 but does not execute/ write

Tags: python, bash, terminal, os.system

I have a bash script that I can run flawlessly in my Rpi terminal in its folder:

```
./veye_mipi_i2c.sh -r -f mirrormode -b 10
```

it works like this: Usage: ./veye_mipi_i2c.sh [-r/w] [-f] function name -p1 param1 -p2 param2 -b bus

options:

-r read

-w write

-f [function name] function name

-p1 [param1] param1 of each function

-p2 [param1] param2 of each function

-b [i2c bus num] i2c bus number

When I try to run it in Python (2) via my Spyder editor with os.system, I get a "0" return which I interpret as "succesfully executed" but in fact the script has not been executed and the functions have not been performed. I know this because the script is suppose to change the camera functioning and by checking the images I take afterwards, I can see that nothing has changed.

```
import os
status = os.system('/home/pi/VeyeMipi/Camera_Folder/veye_mipi_i2c.sh -w -f mirrormode -p1 0x04 -b 10')
print status
```

Any idea, what causes this? The bash script uses two other scripts that lie in the same folder location (read and write). Could it be, that it cannot execute these additional scripts when startet through Python? It does not make sense to me, but so do a lot of things....

Many thanks

Comment: How are we supposed to reproduce the problem here? Run `bash -x /home/pi/...` instead and see what's going on under the hood.

Comment: [veye_mipi_i2c.sh](https://github.com/veyeimaging/veye327_jetson_nano/blob/master/i2c_cmd/bin/veye_mipi_i2c.sh) does not appear to be written to handle failures or return canonical exit codes, so you can not assume that 0 means success

Comment: What happens if you just `exit 1` from the bash script? If you can see that in Python, it just shows you need to work further on extracting a [mcve] for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help if you fix your scripts so they don't depend on the current working directory (that's a very bad practice).

In the meantime, running

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.run(['./veye_mipi_i2c.sh', '-r', '-f', 'mirrormode', '-b', '10'], cwd='/home/pi/VeyeMipi/Camera_Folder')
print(p.returncode)
```

which changes the directory would help.

Comment: Thank you Diego. But how do you deal with this problem if scripts depend on each other? Do you mean I should add the depencies to the system path?

Comment: You can add the scripts to a directory that is already in PATH (i.e. /usr/local/bin) or symlink them there

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I understand that my question was not exemplary because of the lack of a minimal reproducible example, but as I did not understand what the problem was, I was not able to create one.

I have found out, what the problem was. The script I am calling in bash requires two more scripts that are in the same folder. Namely the "write" script and "read" script. When executing in terminal in the folder, no problem, because the folder was the working directory.

I tried to execute the script within Spyder editor and added the file location to the PATH in the user interface. But still it would not be able to execute the "write" script in the folder.

Simply executing it in the terminal did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use subprocess and capture the output:

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.run(stuff, capture_output=True)
```

Check output.stderr and output.stdout